# How to load a huge image in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to load a huge bitmap in flutter? For example I have an image 3000x3000px that I need to display in Image widget with size 100x100px. In android SDK I can use BitmapOption.inSampleSize to load downscaled image. Is there have an analogue in Flutter SDK?

Comment: Not possible. At least not yet.

Answer (score 0):

as an option you can use `ResizeImage` widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ResizeImage img;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    img = ResizeImage(NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/3000/3000'), width: 100, height: 100);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Image(image: img)));
  }
}
```

if you add this code to `initState`

```
img.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(ImageStreamListener((info, bool _)async {
  var data = await info.image.toByteData();
  print('==== ${img.width}   ${img.height}  ${data.buffer.asUint32List().length}');
}));
```

you will see in log something line this

```
==== 100   100 10000
```